# How to get all of one entity but filtered relation in JPQL

Tags: java, jpa, entity, jpql

I have a OneToMany relation between to entities: Area and Reservation. Area has many reservations (or none) and Reservation has one Area.
I would like to query all Area's but for each area, I would only have the Reservations which fullfill a condition.

So far I've tried something like this:

```
em.createQuery("SELECT DISTINCT a FROM Area a LEFT JOIN a.reservations r WHERE r.startDate < :fromDate")
                .setParameter("fromDate", fromDate, TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
                .getResultList();
```

But then it will not return those Areas which does not have any Reservations that fullfill the condition.

Answer (score 0):

This is because your query has a **Where** clause, that doesn't return the records which is present in **Area** but not in **Reservation**.

Here you want something that possibly JPA doesn't support an **ON** clause instead of **Where**.

> JPA JPQL does not support arbitrary relationships between object
>   being defined in the "on" clause

**So what could be the solution for this:**

Using **SQL** Query instead of **JPQL**.

Try something using below based on your objects tables and field value:

```
em.createSQLQuery("SELECT DISTINCT a.area_name FROM area a LEFT JOIN a.reservations r ON r.start_date< :fromDate")
                .setParameter("fromDate", fromDate, TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
                .getResultList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You *cant* populate a `@OneToMany` collection partially. 
Since you have a bi-direcational relationship, you could query the entities the other way round from Reservations:

```
SELECT r FROM Reservation r WHERE r r.startDate < :fromDate
```

This way you have only the Reservations which fullfill your requirement albeit with non distinct Areas.